Is there a way to wait for the Windows Network Stack to be initialized using windows services or c#?
We are working on a windows service that requires ethernet communications using c# .net. However we have a problem where on startup, the windows networking stack / underlying background network processes are not fully up and running when our service attempts to create tcp/ip communications.
Thus we get errors on startup. Is there a way, in code or somewhere in windows where we can delay the connection if the network is not available. It should be noted that while we can constantly ping the connection till it works, if something isn't working properly the service will take too long to boot up. Barring an arbitrary wait, is there something I've missed as a possible solution to this problem.
I have tried a delayed service, but it is not configurable individually and we would prefer not to have to change the delay to a shorter time.
We can delay the service manually but again this is an arbitrary wait and feels weird even though there is very little online regarding this issue.
I have tried to find a service dependency that would wait until the network stack is up and running but I've yet to find one that loads at startup and actually solves the issue. The service needs to keep running so network connections is not an option and server didn't work.

Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855290/which-windows-service-ensures-network-connectivity

@gunr2171 Similar to this yes, however our service doesn't require an internet connection, it just needs to be able to see our NIC. I have tried the combinations of services in the post you linked and some others but that didn't seem to stop our service from running too early and thus hitting socket exceptions.

@dnelson I would suggest to reconsider answer 70632661/9268191 suggesting WinINet.InternetGetConnectedState(), because Microsoft's docs on that API say ...return value of TRUE indicates that either the modem connection is active, or a LAN connection is active. It's not recommended for use in services - but may work and worth a try (I think).

Just a thought: If your service depends on network connection, what does it do if that connection fails during runtime? And how is that situation different from when the connection is not yet ready upon startup? Would you agree that the handling of both would look at least very similar?

^^ in that sense: " if something isn't working properly the service will take too long to boot up." - I wouldn't make that part of the bootstrapping process. Then your service start doesn't time out. A service having been started isn't necessarily the same as it being operational.
